# Querying fields of a particular pagelayout w.r.t Profile and Object

Tags: soql, page-layout, field-level-security

Can we achieve SOQL for this below scenario

If I provide

1. Object Api Name
2. Page Layout Name
3. Profile Name

It should return me list of available fields in the Page Layout, but not all fields present on an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that with SOQL. However, you can get a large part of what you're aiming at with the UI API. From [Get Record Data and Object Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_record_ui.htm):

> `/ui-api/record-ui/{recordIds}`
>
> The response for this request includes layout information, metadata, and record data. The record data includes child relationship data for Contacts and Opportunities.

The Profile that's applied would be the running user for the callout - that is, the logged-in user, if you make the callout from within Salesforce using a session Id, or the user as whom you authenticate if calling from outside Salesforce.

Alternately, you can use the Apex Metadata API to pull down the details of a named page layout, and then manually validate field-level security for each item. See [Metadata Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm#apex_class_Metadata_Operations) for examples of the Apex Metadata API (using Custom Metadata records) and [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_metadata_api/units/apex_metadata_api_updates) for examples of using it to pull page layout details.